# From tkinter get, turn into socket port and host

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create an entry area with tkinter, and based on that input, make it into the host and port, but I keep getting an error no matter how I try

Here is a snippet

```
    self.hostentry = Entry(self.root)
    self.portentry = Entry(self.root)

    s.bind((self.hostentry, self.portentry))
```

All the errors are to do with either the host & portentry not being an int, or this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

use `get` method to fetch that values from the Entry. Cast the value of port to `int`.

```
s.bind((self.hostentry.get().strip(), int(self.portentry.get().strip())))
```